# How do I update azure SQL baseline to remove certain db owners?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I need to update the baseline to reflect only the approved list of owners and remove others.
Can anyone tell me how do I do that?
Here is what I see:
[image]

How do I remove the owners from baseline marked in red?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Another easier way to do this is by clicking on 'Approve as a baseline' after adding or removing the database permissions of the users.

Comment: Adding a user to to the baseline list **is the exact opposite** of removing someone from the all-powerful `db_owner` role. You should choose "Approve as baseline" if that user _really needs_ that level of access. (Though I am sympathetic to the fact it's still a hideously-complex job to figuring out exactly what roles and permissions each principal needs and how to apply those permissions - c'mon Microsoft, _good security should be easy_).

Answer (score 2):

You can remove members from a role using the [sp_droprolemember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-droprolemember-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) stored procedure. Similarly, the stored procedure sp_addrolemember can add additional users to the role.

Here is a statement to remove members from the db_owner role.

```
EXEC sp_droprolemember [db_owner],[<User Name here>]
```

Comment: `sp_droprolemember` is kinda legacy and is documented as deprecated (if not obsolete). [Consider using the ISO SQL-standard `ALTER ROLE` command instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49644940/159145).